# Arm template: get http trigger from staging slot

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I need to get the URL (or code used in URL) of a HTTP Trigger based function in a staging slot.

I'm able to get the trigger_url variable value of the functionapp in the production slot (web/sites/functions). But i'm not able to get the trigger_url value of the functionapp that is in the staging slot.

Example template gets the value of production instead of staging for app setting 'PostUrl'.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "functionAppName": {
            "defaultValue": "functionAppName",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('functionAppName'), '/staging')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "location": "West Europe",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings" : [
                        {
                            "name": "PostUrl",
                            "value":  "[listSecrets(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', parameters('functionAppName'), 'RequestName'),'2015-08-01').trigger_url]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the error message ? Thanks :-)

Comment: This does not give an error. It's a working example. I need to modify it to get the value from a staging slot instead of production website. Thanks

Comment: so you want the `PostUrl` appsettings to contains the slot url ??

Comment: Yes, that's it indeed :)

Comment: To be more specific: the slot url of a HTTP Trigger based function that contains also de needed 'code' parameter to trigger the function. So i need something like this: (pseudo) sites/functionApp/slots/staging/HttpTriggerRequestName.trigger_url

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Are you sure it is working ? When I run the same I have this exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support 
21:01:28 - this configuration.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170837/discussion-between-gyocol-and-thomas).

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---example) for full details on HTTP trigger on Azure functions, If you plan to use the HTTP or WebHook bindings, plan to avoid port exhaustion that can be caused by improper instantiation of HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

The url should is always pretty static by default, just "https://myfunction-myslotname.azurewebsites.net". However, you do need different keys for the slot.

Did you try passing the slot name into the "resourceId" template?

`resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', parameters('functionAppName'), 'RequestName')`

try something like this (replace with your slot name)

`[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('functionAppName'), 'slotname')]`
`[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('functionAppName'), 'RequestName', 'slotname')]`

Your resourceId currently always looks like this, maybe this will also help:

`/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<functionname>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<functionname>/slots/<slotname>`